# Identify groups of numbers in an array (group pixels of an image)

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv

this question is related to another question i asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54661766/find-specific-points-on-an-image). now i have an array of contains 0s,1s,-1s. consider it as an image where background is 0s. i has groups of 1s and -1s.
 [image: array in exel]
This it that array opened in excel. those highlighted groups are 1s( in some cases can be -1s). there can be 4 groups in one array maximum. i want to separate those groups in to left, right, top, bottom with its value and the original index. 
referring to the previous question, i am trying to find the points on the humps and hollows in the puzzle pieces. if i can group them separately then i know how to find the index of the point i want.
i tried to separate like this. but this doesn't apply for all the pieces. some times it can cut through hollows.
 [image: this]
 thanks in advance for any help!!!

Comment: Read about connected components labeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data is 2d array. Have you tried using an approach like region growing to segment the data?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region_growing

Basically, you need to start with a seed point and grow the region by considering neighbouring points and whether or not they fit the criteria for your region.

Comment: I got your idea and wrote my own code to separate those regions into different arrays of the same full size array. now i have all arrays of the humps and hollows stored in a list. i know if it is a hump or a hollow, but still haven't figured out a way to know which is in which side, like left,right,top or bottom. the number of those things can be 2,3,4 depending on the piece. some pieces are not in a normal square shape, so cant get the side just by its coordinates. need to consider some connection between those new array i think.. any idea?

Comment: Ok, now that you have the groups. You could compute the (x,y) centroid of the group (basically its average position) could you then use then information to determine if it's left, right, top or bottom?

Comment: thanks for the reply, i already figured out a way to do that. something slimier to what you explained here